# Unable to perform drag and drop action on an element using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

I am trying to perform drag and drop action on element but its not happening.

This is the snippet of the page I am working on. Here I am trying to drag and place the Tile "Time" in position of the Tile "Approvals".
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUP5J.png)

This is the code I am using.

Code

```
String sSource = "//*[@id=\"PTNUI_LAND_REC14$1_row_0"]";
String sTarget = "//*[@id=\"PTNUI_LAND_REC14$1_row_1"]";
WebElement wSource = TestBase.wDriver.findElement(By.xpath(sSource));
WebElement wTarget = TestBase.wDriver.findElement(By.xpath(sTarget));
Actions aActions = new Actions(TestBase.wDriver);
Action aDragAndDrop = aActions.clickAndHold(wSource).moveToElement(wTarget).release(wTarget).build();
aDragAndDrop.perform();
```

HTML

Source Element

```
    <div class="ps_grid-row nuitile rsz_w1 rsz_h1" id="PTNUI_LAND_REC14$1_row_0" tx="1.0577777777777777" ty="1" gx=".1.0577777777777777." gy=".1.">
    <div class="ps_grid-cell">
    <div id="win0divPTNUI_LAND_REC_GROUPLET$13" class="ps_box-group psc_layout nuilp " tabindex="0" draggable="true" aria-dropeffect="move" aria-grabbed="false" droppable="true">
    <h2 class="ps_groupleth"><span class="ps-label" id="PTNUI_LAND_REC_GROUPLET_LBL$13">Approvals</span></h2>
```

Target Element

```
<div class="ps_grid-row nuitile rsz_w1 rsz_h1" id="PTNUI_LAND_REC14$1_row_1" tx="2.057777777777778" ty="1" gx=".2.057777777777778." gy=".1.">
<div class="ps_grid-cell">
<div id="win0divPTNUI_LAND_REC_GROUPLET$14" class="ps_box-group psc_layout nuilp " tabindex="0" draggable="true" aria-dropeffect="move" aria-grabbed="false" droppable="true">
<div id="win0groupletPTNUI_LAND_REC_GROUPLET$14" class="ps_box-grouplet"><img id="PT_PORTAL_CLEAR_DOT$14" class="ps_process" src="/cs/p91h25r2x/cache/PT_PORTAL_CLEAR_DOT_1.gif" alt=""></div>
<h2 class="ps_groupleth"><span class="ps-label" id="PTNUI_LAND_REC_GROUPLET_LBL$14">Time</span></h2></div></div>
```

Please let me know if you require any more details.

Comment: Do you see any errors? Update the Question with the error stack trace.

Comment: The implementation here is an HTML 5 drop and drop which is as far as I know still not supported via mouse down/mouve/up. One option is to simulate the DND with a script injection: https://gist.github.com/florentbr/60ef7cb8d9b1ae690cafc82aad52da73

Comment: @FlorentB. I am not sure how to analyze if it is HTML 5 and draggable/droppable or not. But I can clearly see `draggable="true"` and `droppable="true"` for both the elements. Doesn't that leaves an impression both the elements can be dragged/dropped?

Comment: @DebanjanB - I am not getting any exceptions while executing. The problem is nothing is happening.

Comment: @FlorentB - Can you tell me how you understood that this is a html 5 drag and drop?

Comment: draggable and droppable are attributes introduced by HTML5. That alone tells me that the implementation rely on the [drag and drop API/Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to target on draggable elements as given below.

```
String sSource = "//*[@id=\"win0divPTNUI_LAND_REC_GROUPLET$13"]";
String sTarget = "//*[@id=\"win0divPTNUI_LAND_REC_GROUPLET$14"]";
WebElement wSource = TestBase.wDriver.findElement(By.xpath(sSource));
WebElement wTarget = TestBase.wDriver.findElement(By.xpath(sTarget));
Actions aActions = new Actions(TestBase.wDriver);
aActions.dragAndDrop(wSource, wTarget).build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but its also not working.

Answer (score 0):

To `Drag` and `Drop` the Tile **Approvals** in position of the Tile **Time** you can use the following code block :

```
WebElement  from = TestBase.wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ps_box-group psc_layout nuilp ' and contains(id,'win0divPTNUI_LAND_REC_GROUPLET$13')]"));
WebElement  to = TestBase.wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ps_box-group psc_layout nuilp ' and contains(id,'win0divPTNUI_LAND_REC_GROUPLET$14')]"));
new Actions(TestBase.wDriver).dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();
System.out.println("Drag and Drop Completed");
```

Comment: Did you check out this Answer? Let me know the status.